# Trouble loading an SKMapFragment into a ViewPager

Tags: android-fragments, skmaps, skobbler-maps

Since it appears that the ViewPager class only supports android.support.v4.app.Fragment Fragments (and their FragmentManagers), I am unable to create a ViewPager which has an SKMapFragment as one of its Fragments, since SKMapFragment extends android.app.Fragment.
Is this a known issue and if so, how can I tackle it?

Comment: We've asked the help of our developers